# Is there a standard name for "signed distance to the nearest integer" that's reasonably succinct?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, integers, cryptography, music-theory

> **Notation.** Write $\mathbb{R}_\mathbb{Z}$ for the set of all real numbers for which there exists a unique nearest integer. Explicitly:
>
> $$\mathbb{R}_\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{R} \setminus(0.5 + \mathbb{Z}),$$ where the backslash denotes [relative complementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)).

Given a real number $x$ not of the form $n/2$ where $n$ is an integer, write $\lfloor x \rceil$ for the nearest integer (I've read that this is standard notation in cryptography, which is the only reason I included cryptography in the tags). In this notation, the *signed distance to the nearest integer* is the function defined below. $$f : \mathbb{R}_\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow (-0.5, 0.5), \quad f(x) = x - \lfloor x \rceil.$$

> **Question.** Is there a standard name for this function (and/or the number it produces) that's reasonably succinct? E.g. the *deviation* of $x$, the *residue* of $x$, the *deficiency* of $x$, etc.

*Motivation.* This function shows up whenever we try to fit microtonal music into a semitonal context. For example, suppose I have tune $C$ to its standard [12TET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament) value. Suppose I want $E$ to be a [JI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_intonation) major third above that. The question arises of how far to retune $E$ from its standard 12TET value in order to achieve this goal. The JI ratio for the major third is $5/4$, and consequently its semitonal size is $12 \log_2(5/4).$ Hence the amount we have to retune $E$ is $f(12 \log_2(5/4))$. Since this is approximately $-0.14$, this tells us that we need to flatten $E$ by about $14\%$ of a semitone to achieve our goal. In the hope of communicating with other musicians more easily, I'd therefore like to have a succinct name for this function.

Comment: People disagree.  For a while, $\lfloor x\rceil$ was proposed, but it never caught on, see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerFunction.html).  I agree, it seems like something that needs a simple notation.

Comment: "In the hope of communicating with other musicians more easily, I'd therefore like to have a succinct name for this function." While it might seem like a good idea, I don't think this is the best way to reach other musicians. In a music context I would simply call it pitch deviation (from whatever base tuning we have agreed on).

Comment: @dtldarek honestly, I don't see much of a difference between what you're proposing and what I'm proposing, except that I'd prefer my terminology to be consistent with existing mathematical standards if possible.

Comment: @goblin But wouldn't music standards be more appropriate when you want to use this to communicate with musicians? From math perspective I don't see the difference either.